# how to order by 1 in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this Django template, which works

`template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s ORDER BY "col_name")'`

However, I want to replace "col_name" with 1, e.g.

`template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s ORDER BY 1)'`

This does not do the ordering properly

what can I do?

Comment: Well if you `ORDER BY 1`, all fields are given some "hidden" column with value `1`, so that means that there is no real order, since each ordering is `ORDER BY 1`.

Comment: Exactly *what* do you want to achieve by `ORDER BY 1`?

Comment: I used this and it worked ```template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s ORDER BY %(expressions)s)'```
expression has a tuple of fields (column names) passed in, and I want to order by the fields (column names) within the function

Comment: but then you `ORDER BY col1, col2, col3`. So you mention the column names in a comma separated sequence.

Comment: yeah, I actually only want to order by col1, ordering by all columns is the closest I found to a working solution so far